# custom delegate method not call

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

i have first display start_game screen than after when i click button that time display popupview using xib.in xib class i have create delegate method.when i close the popupview that time call delegate method but not calling

here is my delegate class
    .h File
    #import

```
@protocol digbuttonalertdelegate;

@interface digbuttonalert : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bg_image;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<digbuttonalertdelegate> delegate;
@end
@protocol digbuttonalertdelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void)digalertclose;
@end

.m File

#import "digbuttonalert.h"
#import "suggestion_alert.h"
#import "UIViewController+CWPopup.h"
#import "zoom_alert.h"
@interface digbuttonalert ()
{
    bool status;
}
@end

@implementation digbuttonalert

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    status=0;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.bg_image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.bg_image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {
   }
-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

    if(status==0)
    {
        self.lbl_title.text=@"As you walk you will discover the hidden map.This circle will show your progress.";
        status=1;
    }
    else
    {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(digalertclose)]) {
            [self.delegate digalertclose];

        }


    }



}
```

here this class i want to call method

```
 #import "digbuttonalert.h"
     @interface start_games ()  <MJSecondPopupDelegate,digbuttonalertdelegate>
    {
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
digbuttonalert *next=[[digbuttonalert alloc]init];
    next.delegate=self;

    next.modalTransitionStyle=UIWebPaginationModeRightToLeft;
    next.modalPresentationStyle=17;
    [self presentViewController:next animated:YES completion:nil];


            }
        - (void)digalertclose
        {

            [self StartTimer];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"false" forKey:@"alertstatus"];
        }
```

Comment: from where you are pushing digalertClose view controller?

Comment: @NinjaHattori in viewdidload puching digalertClose vc

Comment: Can you please share that code?

Comment: @NinjaHattori i will added code

Comment: If its view controller, You should initialise with XIB or Initiate from storyboard or Override Init method in view controller..I am surprised..Is it displaying your view when you Present it ?

Comment: and why your are presenting view controller from ViewdidLoad ?

Comment: Instead of defining digbuttonalert *next=[[digbuttonalert alloc]init]; ...try creating global object of next and use it.

Comment: @NinjaHattori ok i will try

Comment: @NinjaHattori it doesn't really matter if view controller object is global or not.

Comment: @iosdv Is tapDetected method is getting called?

Answer (score 0):

Change .m file with below :

```
@protocol digbuttonalertdelegate <NSObject>
    @optional
    -(void)digalertclose;
 @end

 @interface digbuttonalert : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bg_image;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_title;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<digbuttonalertdelegate> delegate;
 @end
```

And follow basic tutorial steps : [enter link description here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Please implement `digalertclose` delegate in `start_games` controller like this

```
-(void)digalertclose {
}
```

You make `digalertclose` optional thats why crash does not occur if you remove `optional` keyword from `digbuttonalertdelegate` protocol you can see that there will be a crash because you try to fire a delegate but does not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your digbuttonalert.h protocol is defined twice.
2. There is no @end for the interface.

Should be something like

ClassA.h

```
@protocol YourProtocol <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)yourProtocolOptionalMethod

@end

@interface ClassA.h 

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <YourProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
-(void) someClassAMethod {
     [self.delegate yourProtocolOptionalMethod];
}
```

ClassB.h

```
#import "ClassA.h"
@interface ClassB <YourProtocol>

@end
```

ClassB.m

```
-(void) someClassBMethod {
    ClassA *classA = [ClassA alloc] init];
    classA.delegate = self;
}
```

After setting the delegate now when you will call the delegate from ClassA then it will trigger the protocol implemented method in ClassB

```
-(void)yourProtocolOptionalMethod {
    NSlog(@"");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On your class , you need to declare the delegate like this:

```
@interface YourViewController () < digbuttonalertdelegate >
```

Comment: @NinjaHattori if he is using the delegates, then he must have to specify `@interface YourViewController () < digbuttonalertdelegate >` and `obj.delgate = self`.
**TUTORIAL-->** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm